# Ввод без перехода на следующую строку C#

Tags: c#

Я хочу сделать, чтоб при вводе данных в C# не выполнялся переход на новую строку в консоли, это возможно?
Например, чтоб консоль выглядела не так:

```
Введите числа: 1,

2,

3.
```

а так:

```
Введите числа: 1,2,3.
```

помню в паскале были `read` и `readln`, есть ли тут аналоги?

Comment: Что мешает считать строку `1,2,3` от юзера и дальше в коде ее распилить и распарсить?

Comment: Напишите свой аналог, используя `Console.Read()`

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать Split в паре с Linq'ом.

```
string read = Console.ReadLine(); // input: 1,200,1333,100000
var numbers = read.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)); // 1, 200, 1333, 100000 в числовом представлении
```

Comment: Зачем `x => int.Parse(x)`, когда можно просто `int.Parse`?

Comment: Зачем Console.ReadLine, если есть формы с полями?

Comment: я не об этом. Для чего Вы создаёте лямбду `<string, int>`, когда `int.Parse` итак является делегатом с такой же подписью?

Comment: 1. Привычка
2. Чтобы человеку было понятней
3. Замечание ваше притянуто за уши

Comment: если бы это было замечанием, я бы минусанул ответ, показывая этим, что мне что-то не нравится) Тут же я просто поинтересовался. Отчасти для того, чтобы тот же ТС понимал, что необязательно писать так, как написали Вы, что существует более короткая форма) Так что не обижайтесь, пожалуйста)

Comment: Я просто написал свое решение задачи, привычка писать в виде x => .... уже давно

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, хорошо, что написали, я так тоже по инерции туплю, а можно же как вы проще, и правильней.

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть на более компактный код, продемонстрируете?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov а почему вы сигнатуру подписью называете? дословный перевод вас устраивает?

Comment: @LiptonDev: он компактнее на пару символов и один вызов побочной функции ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Так что в отдельный ответ выносить - не вижу смысла) Однако могу дать ответ с альтернативным подходом и написании своей функции считывания следующего значения по аналогии с вышеуказанным `read`)

Comment: @4per: отчасти. Вообще, употребление терминов прямо зависит от нашего окружения. Кому-то привычнее все переводить дословно, кто-то придерживается родных названий. Лично я все же более склонен к первому варианту (отсчёт с 0) по одной простой причине: оригинальные названия чаще лучше отражают суть, нежели их переведённые аналоги. А также перевести термин порой можно столькими разными способами, что волосы дыбом встают ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Так что ‘сигнатура’ мне действительно более по душе, нежели ‘подпись’, но из-за текущего рабочего окружения...)